# What is the difference between T5 and T0 models?

Tags: deep-learning, natural-language-processing, gpt, language-model

What is the difference between T5 and T0 models? I had read that T0 is T5 + LM. But as I know T5 uses encoder-decoder model like BART but BART can be used as LM so that's mean that T5 has a LM function too. So what is the difference between T5 and T0 then?

Comment: Can you provide more context? Where did you find these terms? Provide a link.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

T0 starts with T5+LM as the base model but then performs multi-task finetuning on it using BIG-Bench tasks. As detailed in the Results section (Section 6) of their [paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/2110.08207.pdf), T0 outperforms T5+LM on a number of tasks.